# Error while filling empty rows with mean values using Simple Imputer

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am trying to fill mean values for columns in my data frame.

Here are the values in these 2 columns:

```
0   -3.0    NaN
1   25.0    NaN
2   25.0    NaN
3   1937.0  NaN
4   1965.0  NaN
5   1993.0  NaN
6   2021.0  NaN
7   2021.0  NaN
8   2049.0  NaN
9   2077.0  NaN
10  2105.0  NaN
11  2133.0  NaN
12  2161.0  NaN
13  2189.0  NaN
14  2217.0  NaN

from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer 
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')

imputer = imputer.fit(data[['column1']])
data['column1'] = imputer.transform(data[['column1']]).ravel()

imputer = imputer.fit(data[['column2']])
data['column2'] = imputer.transform(data[['column2']]).ravel()
```

While the first imputer.fit works fine the second one throws an error.

Here is the error "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index" and entire error stack below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-44682728650c> in <module>()
      3 
      4 imputer = imputer.fit(data[['column2']])
----> 5 data['column2'] = imputer.transform(data[['column2']]).ravel()

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3368         else:
   3369             # set column
-> 3370             self._set_item(key, value)
   3371 
   3372     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3443 
   3444         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
-> 3445         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
   3446         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   3447 

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _sanitize_column(self, key, value, broadcast)
   3628 
   3629             # turn me into an ndarray
-> 3630             value = sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)
   3631             if not isinstance(value, (np.ndarray, Index)):
   3632                 if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) > 0:

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in sanitize_index(data, index, copy)
    517 
    518     if len(data) != len(index):
--> 519         raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of index')
    520 
    521     if isinstance(data, ABCIndexClass) and not copy:

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Comment: Can you share a part of the dataframe ? The problem comes from it more than the imputer.

Comment: @NicolasM. Here are the values in the columns

Comment: is there at least a not-NaN value in column 2? The strategy "mean" requires at least one numerical value.

Comment: @NicolasM that was it. Sorry I did not check that in the first place.